# Output Integer to stdout in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io

I have a simple function like:

```
nth :: Integer -> Integer
```

And I try to print it's result as follows:

```
main = do
    n <- getLine
    result <- nth (read n :: Integer)
    print result
```

The following error is generated:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO t0' with actual type `Integer'
In the return type of a call of `nth'
In a stmt of a 'do' expression:
    result <- nth (read n :: Integer)
```

Also tried with `putStrLn` and a lot of other combinations with no luck.
I can't figure it out and I would need some help, being that I don't fully understand how stuff works around these `IO`s.

Comment: one-liner: `main = print . nth . read =<< getLine`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`nth` is a function, not an `IO` action:

```
main = do
  n <- getLine
  let result = nth (read n :: Integer)
  print result
```

Comment: Because it doesn't do any I/O...?

Comment: Do syntax and binds (`x <- action`) is only used for Monads.  If you are a beginner then chances are the only monad you're using is `IO`.  if your function isn't in the form `func :: a -> IO b` or even just `func :: IO b`, then you can't use bind but you can use a let statement.

Comment: Great, thanks. But what's the difference between using a `let` before `print` and call directly `print nth (read...)`?

Comment: There is no difference. `print (nth (read n :: Integer))` will work as well. `<-` is not to save intermediate values - it's to unwrap monadic values. Use `let` to save intermediate values (in `do` blocks `let` has slightly different syntax than outside of do blocks) and `<-` to extract values from monadic values.

Answer (score 7):

The `do` syntax unwraps something within a monad. Everything on the right hand side of the arrow must live within the IO monad, otherwise the types don't check. An `IO Integer` would be fine in your program. `do` is syntactic sugar for the more explicit function which would be written as follows:

Recall that `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`

```
main = getLine >>= (\x ->
       nth >>= (\y ->
       print y))
```

But `nth` is not a monadic value, so it doesn't make sense to apply the function `(>>=)`, which requires something with the type `IO a`.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm like "Oh, so from here came that expected `m0 a0` I was receiving..."

Comment: To clarify little more, `m0` comes from the fact that `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. It works for any monad, not only `IO`, and in your case compiler didn't have a chance to figure out that `m` is `IO`, so it put `m0` in the error message.